# Adding new row using values from other rows

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a Pandas dataframe. I want to add a new row at a specific location, e.g. after 1st row. And I want the value of cells in the new row to be assigned using values from rows 1 and 2, buth only if the values in both the rows are not equal to zero.

```
States  Andhra Pradesh  Bihar   Chhattisgarh    Delhi
1973-74    50.67        56.01         0         60.99
1977-78    69.66        57.45         0         95.85
1983       115.4        93.75       100        217.14
1993-94    288.7        218.3       130        605.22
```

```
import pandas as pd
import math
data1= pd.read_excel('C:\\Users\\3004\\Desktop\\Variables.xlsx',3,index_col = 0)
data1.loc[8] = math.exp(math.log(data1.loc['1977-78']/data1.loc['1973-74'])/4)*data1.loc['1973-74']
```

Output expected:

```
States  Andhra Pradesh  Bihar   Chhattisgarh    Delhi
1973-74    50.67        56.01         0         60.99
1975       54.87        56.37         0         68.29
1977-78    69.66        57.45         0         95.85
1983       115.4        93.75       100        217.14
1993-94    288.7        218.3       130        605.22
```

First value of row 1975 is got as "EXP(LN(69.66/50.67)/4)*50.57"

However, I am getting an error message `"TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>"`

Comment: Could you add an expected output, also in the form of a dataframe, so we can visually see what you try to achieve.

Comment: added the output expected